# pythonでリストを読み込んでファイルを検索し、変更日時を取得したい

Tags: python

python3でリストからIDを読み込んで、パスを取得するコードを作成しました
（フォルダ上でのファイルの有無を確認するため）

```
import glob
import re
import os

f = open('myList.txt', 'r')
for line in f:

  myPath=r"\\12.345.67.89\AA\BB"
  text=r"{}\{}\*MYID\*.pdf"
  result=text.format(myPath,line.rstrip('\n'))
  l = glob.glob(result)
  print(l)

f.close
```

リストはmyList.txtというファイルで
A11122
B22222
C12345
とIDを記載しています

これを以下のように変更して、ファイル名だけでなく、ファイルの変更日時も取得したいのですが上手くいきません。どこを修正したらよいか教えていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。OSはWindows10です

```
import glob
import re
import os

f = open('myList.txt', 'r')
for line in f:

  myPath=r"\\12.345.67.89\AA\BB"
  text=r"{}\{}\*MYID\*.pdf"
  result=text.format(myPath,line.rstrip('\n'))
  l = glob.glob(result)
  for x in glob.glob(result)
  print(os.path.getmtime(l))

f.close
```

Comment: payaneco様、ありがとうございます！思っていた通りに動きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手元のpython3.6環境でサンプルコードのように書き換えると正常に動作しました。(ファイルサーバが原因と限らないので、とりあえずローカル環境にしています)
下記を見直してもエラーが出る場合は、質問にエラーメッセージの追記をお願いします。

- `for x...`のネストができていない
- for文の中で`x`を使わずに配列`l`を渡している

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import glob
import re
import os
from datetime import datetime

f = open('myList.txt', 'r')
for line in f:

  myPath=r"test" 
  text=r"{}\{}\*MYID\*.pdf" 
  result=text.format(myPath,line.rstrip('\n'))
  l = glob.glob(result)
  l = glob.glob(result)
  for x in glob.glob(result):
    print(os.path.getmtime(x))
    print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(x)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

f.close
```